# 2TB NVMe slow in Linux only after booting Windows

Tags: performance, ssd, nvme

My SSD is a 2TB PCIe 3.0 x4 M.2 NVMe (Mega Fastro MS200, some Korean brand, on sale under $100 in Germany). According to Windows smi_nvme_flash_id.exe utility it is a SM2262EN controller with Intel 96L TLC NAND and 2G DRAM cache. Firmware revision 42AAT7GD. Its seated on internal slot directly connected to CPU.

For performance testing, I filled it with a few hundred gigabytes of /dev/random data. The oddity lies in reading speed for that random data.

When I turn on the PC and boot into ArchLinux directly (6.2.8 kernel), the read speed is very fast:

```
  # echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
  # cat /dev/nvme0n1p1 |
    ( pv -S -s 222G > /dev/null
      hexdump -C -n 32 )
```

###### 222GiB 0:01:35 [2.34GiB/s] [======================================>] 100%

```
 00000000  b2 ce c5 36 de 56 bd 05  1f 65 82 8e 1c 23 18 07  |...6.V...e...#..|
 00000010  03 0e b1 44 ec 6c 2c b0  64 47 d5 47 a6 59 cc 8b  |...D.l,.dG.G.Y..|
 00000020
```

I can use md5sum instead of > dev/null and verify it always reads the same random data, just that md5sum, is a bit slower than devnull.

So every thing is fine except. When I reboot into Windows 10, and reboot back into Linux. Without doing anything else. The read speed for the exact same procedure is suddenly capped slightly below 1 GiB/s.

222G of data exceeds my RAM by a lot so it can't be a cache related. Temperature stays within normal boundaries (up to 80°C under load). I will try to add a cooler but I doubt it will be a difference. I can repeat the above command multiple times in a row and it always stays fast even with temperature already high. And if anything rebooting into Windows (not stored on this SSD) and back should give it time to cool down.

lspci output does not change, shows the device as running in PCIe 3.0 x4 modus. dmesg does not change. /sys/block/nvme0n1/** does not change. smartctl -a does not change. I don't know where to look.

Reboot again and it stays slow. Turn the machine off, then back on and boot Linux, it's back to the original much faster speed. Reboot into Linux, stays fast. Reboot Windows, then Linux, back to slow.

Is it possible, that Windows sets up some kind of limit, which sticks even after rebooting into Linux? If so, is there any way, to reset it with out cold restarting?